# In which directories does GNOME Do look?

Tags: launcher, gnome-do, directory

I have 2 launchers for an application with the same name but that do different things. I'd like to delete one of them so that the one that comes up in GNOME Do is the right one.

The problem is that I don't recall where the launchers are located.

In which directories does GNOME Do look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launchers are located in `/usr/share/applications/` and `~/.local/share/applications/`.
Since you created the launchers, they are probably in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem! (doesn't answer the GNOME Do question though!)

Comment: @Olivier That *is* where Gnome Do looks. Those are the only standard directories for launchers.